# Managing text inside files in Python

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, text, copy

Suppose I have two txt files,  `in.txt` and `out.txt`.

**in.txt**:

```
Mary is Passed 
Jane is Failed
```

**out.txt**:

```
Status of Mary: 'N/A'
Status of Jane: 'N/A'
```

I want to write Python code which reads `in.txt` and replaces the 'N/A' with `Passed` for Mary and `Failed` for Jane in `out.txt`.

I could manage to write at the end of the line of `out.txt` but not at 'N/A'

Comment: please add your code and exact output, then its easy to solve your problem.

Comment: is it possible to use regex to replace each line's `'N/A'` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

...

outf = open('myout', 'r+')
inf = open('infile', 'r')
outdata = outf.read()
for line in inf:
    outdata = re.sub("(?<=Status of %s: )'N/A'" % line.strip().split()[0], line.strip().split()[2], outdata)
outf.write(outdata)
outf.close()
inf.close()
```

Comment: I think this will work but this traceback appears when I run this code. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./stack.py", line 11, in <module>
    outdata = re.sub("(?<=Status of %s: )'N/A'" % line.strip().split()[0], line.strip().split()[2])
TypeError: sub() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here on a related question: [Deleting a line in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822771/deleting-a-line-in-a-file/19823146#19823146)

Bascially, editing the bytes in the middle of a file is no fun. You should just read the file in memory and overwrite it at the end if it's not too large, or use something like [tempfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.htm) if it is real large.