# Python Insert text before a specific line

Tags: python, regex

I want to insert a text specifically before a line 'Number'.

I want to insert 'Hello Everyone' befor the line starting with 'Number'

My code:

```
import re
result = []
with open("text2.txt", "r+") as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f] # stores all lines from f into an array and removes "\n"
    # Find the first occurance of "Centre" and store its index
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith("Number"): # same as your re check
            break
    ind = a.index(item) #here it produces index no./line no.
    result.extend(a[:ind])
        f.write('Hello Everyone')
```

tEXT FILE:

```
QWEW
RW
...
Number hey
Number ho
```

Expected output:

```
QWEW
RW
...
Hello Everyone
Number hey
Number ho
```

Please help me to fix my code:I dont get anything inserted with my text file!Please help!
Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: open("text2.txt", "r") won't allow you to write to the file

Comment: even by making changes i dont get it inserted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem

When you do `open("text2.txt", "r")`, you open your file for **reading**, not for **writing**. Therefore, nothing appears in your file.

#### The fix

Using `r+` instead of `r` allows you to also write to the file (this was also pointed out in the comments. However, it *overwrites*, so be careful (this is an OS limitation, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125703/how-do-i-modify-a-text-file-in-python)). The following should do what you desire: It inserts `"Hello everyone"` into the list of lines and then overwrites the file with the updated lines.

```
with open("text2.txt", "r+") as f:
    a = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
    index = 0
    for item in a:
        if item.startswith("Number"):
            a.insert(index, "Hello everyone") # Inserts "Hello everyone" into `a`
            break
        index += 1
    # Go to start of file and clear it
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    # Write each line back
    for line in a:
        f.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer to your problem is the [`hlt`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106415/hlt) one, but consider also using the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
import fileinput

found = False
for line in fileinput.input('DATA', inplace=True):
    if not found and line.startswith('Number'):
        print 'Hello everyone'
        found = True
    print line,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python): they propose to do it in three steps: read everything / insert / rewrite everything

```
with open("/tmp/text2.txt", "r") as f:
lines = f.readlines()

for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith("Number"):
        break
lines.insert(index, "Hello everyone !\n")

with open("/tmp/text2.txt", "w") as f:
    contents = f.writelines(lines)
```