# Insert new line in CSV at second row via Python

Tags: python, csv, insert, row

Is it possible to insert a new line in a CSV file at the 2nd row?  For example, I have a CSV with column names and their values:

```
meter_id, sdp_id, lat, lon
813711, 1331, 34.298, -83.113
```

The application I'm attempting to read this file into requires a new line added indicating the column type.  In the above example all would be string, so the CSV would need to be:

```
meter_id, sdp_id, lat, lon
String, String, String, String
813711, 1331, 34.298, -83.113
```

I've read several posts how to add a new line at the end of the CSV, but couldn't find anything on how to do the above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert line at middle of file with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one approach using `csv` module.

**Demo:**

```
import csv
toAdd = ["String", "String", "String", "String"]
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(infile))
    reader.insert(1, toAdd)

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: thank you for this answer.  It's working, but it is entering an empty row between is row in the updated CSV.

Comment: Use `with open(filename, "w", newline='') as outfile:` if you are in python3

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.14.

Comment: Then use `with open(filename, "wb") as outfile:`

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution could be:

```
import csv

row = ['String', ' String', ' String']

with open('file.csv', 'r') as readFile:
    reader = csv.reader(readFile)
    lines = list(reader)
    lines.insert(1, row)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as writeFile:
    writer = csv.writer(writeFile)
    writer.writerows(lines)

readFile.close()
writeFile.close()
```

I could not try it. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I'm noticing is that this is adding an extra row between each row in the updated CSV.