# Insert contents of a file in middle of another file with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is already a question on SO that explains how to insert a line into the middle of a python file at a specific line number.

But what if I have 2 files. `inputfile.txt` and `outputfile.txt` (which already has some text) and I want to insert *all* of `inputfile.txt` (with formatting preserved) into the middle of `outputfile.txt`?

Comment: No OS supports inserting text into the middle of a text file.

Comment: I thought you could insert a line at a specific point into a text file, using python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python

Comment: I believe it will be the exact same as the question in the link you posted

Comment: That is not "inserting a line into a file", that is "creating a new file with the line inserted".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think it is any different from this [probable SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python) you are referring to?

Its just that instead of inserting a line, you need to read your `inputfile.txt` into a variable as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369219/how-do-i-read-a-text-file-into-a-string-variable-in-python)
and insert that into the file, instead of the `value` as clearly shown in the question. (links provided above)

Answer (score 0):

## insert contents of "/inputFile.txt" into "/outputFile.txt" at line 90

```
with open("/inputFile.txt", "r") as f1:
    t1 = f1.readlines()
with open("/outputFile.txt", "r") as f2:
    t2 = f2.readlines()
t2.insert(90, t1)
with open("/outputFile.txt", "w") as f2:
    f2.writelines(t2)
```

That should do it