# Python Find specific line in File and append below it

Tags: python, file, search, append

I'm trying to append only after certain sections in this file I would like the be able to find the specific section by string value then add to it.

```
\\ desk



\\ phone



\\ chairs



\\tv
```

so that it looks like so

```
\\desk    # CODE finds '\\desk' then appends below it or above
wood
metal
etc

\\phone   # CODE finds '\\phone' then appends below it or above
cell
landline 
etc

\\chairs

\\tv
```

I know the solution is probably insanely easy and I swear I've done it before but apparently I have been asking google/the rest of the internet the wrong question.

if more clarification is needed basically i have a function that takes in args that will append certain sections based on what was selected and it has to run multiple times so I believe that appending is the way to go.

Comment: does it answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def append(filename, **args):
    with open(filename) as f:
        text = [x for x in f.read().splitlines() if x]

    for k, v in args.items():
        k = r"\\ "+k
        if k not in text:
            continue

        i = text.index(k)
        for n in reversed(v):
            text.insert(i+1, n)

    return "\n".join(text)

print(append(
    "file.txt",
    desk=["wood", "metal", "etc"],
    phone=["cell", "landline", "etc"]
))
```

Output:

```
\\ desk
wood
metal
etc
\\ phone
cell
landline
etc
\\ chairs
\\tv
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes this worked out amazingly just needed to tweak it a bit to fit le code and perfection. Even though I did not intend  to pass list I like the extra mile you went ! Thank you for your quick response too !