# How to insert text while loop file lines in append and read mode

Tags: python

I am trying to add a text in a line while looping the file in append and read mode. Below is the code that does not work i.e. does not write the text in the middle of loop line.

```
file = open('path/to/file.txt','a+')
file.seek(0, 0)
line=file.readline()
while line:
    if line=="2ND LINE":
        file.write(",new text")
    line=file.readline()
file.close()
```

What I am trying to do:

```
1ST LINE
2ND LINE,new text
3RD LINE
```

Comment: @DarrylG. Unfortunately Yes. But it is not a solution but a fact from line 'The reason for this is that textfiles are not designed for random access' from the answer.

Comment: @Dhay--retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing a line like this is probably not going to work due to line endings. You either need to check if the line equals `2ND LINE\n` or do a comparison differently like so `if "2ND LINE" in line:`

But you can do it something like this:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput('path/to/file.txt', inplace=1):
    if "2ND LINE" in line:
        line = line.replace(line, line.strip() + ",new text\n")
    print(line, end='')
```

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507230/insert-line-at-middle-of-file-with-python).

Comment: Worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can only accomplish what you want by reading the entire file and then rewriting it:

```py
#soInsertTextInFile
with open('file3.txt','r') as file:
    lines = file.read().split('\n')

with open('file3.txt','w') as file:
    fileLines = 1
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
        file.write(line)
        if fileLines == 2:
            print('write') 
            file.write(",new text")
        file.write('\n')
        fileLines += 1
```

Output as requested.

btw this program counts the lines. You may want a different test to decide when to append something to the current line.